# Mulitquery Mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently the query pulls Managed_Funds.  How would also pull Studies from the second query where I want it to go? Or is this build not advanced enough for what I want?

I am new to MYSQLi.

```
<?php

$ID_CARTERA= '8';

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","carteras_admin","","carteras_bdcarteras");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT    

      C.DES_CARTERA_CC  Managed_Funds,      
      A.ANOMES_DESDE Date_Since,
      A.ANOMES_HASTA Final_Date
FROM      det_personas_carteraadmin A
      JOIN mcarteras B  ON ( A.ID_PERSONA = B.COD_ADMINISTRADOR )
      JOIN mcarteras C  ON ( C.ID_CARTERA = A.ID_CARTERA )
WHERE     A.ID_PERSONA = B.COD_ADMINISTRADOR
AND       A.`ANOMES_HASTA`    <>   'A Hoy'
AND       B.`ID_CARTERA`      = $ID_CARTERA;
";
$query .= "SELECT    A.DES_ESTUDIOS Studies
FROM      det_personas_estudios A
      JOIN mcarteras B  ON ( A.ID_PERSONA = B.COD_ADMINISTRADOR )
WHERE     B.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA

";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row['Managed_Funds']);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. I have no idea what Studies is. Show  us some table schemas.

Comment: Studies is located- $query .= "SELECT    A.DES_ESTUDIOS Studies

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the queries separately

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT ... ";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {...}

$query  = "SELECT ... ";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {...}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Or do you mean this?

```
$query  = "SELECT    
       C.DES_CARTERA_CC  Managed_Funds,      
      A.ANOMES_DESDE Date_Since,
      A.ANOMES_HASTA Final_Date,
      A.DES_ESTUDIOS Studies # <------ extra line here
FROM      det_personas_carteraadmin A
      JOIN mcarteras B  ON ( A.ID_PERSONA = B.COD_ADMINISTRADOR )
      JOIN mcarteras C  ON ( C.ID_CARTERA = A.ID_CARTERA )
WHERE     A.ID_PERSONA = B.COD_ADMINISTRADOR
AND       A.`ANOMES_HASTA`    <>   'A Hoy'
AND       B.`ID_CARTERA`      = $ID_CARTERA;
";
```

Comment: I am building a table of data that requires two queries?  Can I not use the multi query method for this?